# Which one have precedence ? Window API and compilation phase?

Tags: javascript

I wonder whether bind() execute sooner than variables initialization or 
    not?
    I found obj is undefined when bind() is executed
    I've learned variables hoisting but I don't understand this situation about executing orders when Window APIs join in .

```
 var obj = {
   foo:(function(){
     return this
   }).bind(obj)
 }

obj.foo() //Window
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when they expression for values of keys in objects are being evaluated at that time the object variable can't be accessed because it is not initialized.

```js
var obj = {
   test:obj
}
console.log(obj.test) //undefined
```

> I wonder whether `bind()` execute sooner than variables initialization or not?

Yes it executes before the initialization of the object.